# Why is this invocation of Activator.CreateInstance failing?

Tags: c#

The runtime error is:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Gorp' from assembly 'foopy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'

Here is *all* the code for both of the two classes in the project:

```cs
using System;

namespace foopy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object myObject;
            myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Gorp");
        }
    }
}

namespace foopy
{
    class Gorp
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_String_System_String_) for that second parameter:

> **`typeName`** String
>
> The **fully qualified** name of the preferred type.

(emphasis mine).

You need to pass the fully-qualified name of the type, including the namespace. So `"foopy.Gorp"`.